# How to perform row mean in matrix by 3 number of columns in sequence using R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with dimension `100x300` where I want to reduce number of columns, `300`, into 100 columns by averaging per 3 columns, i.e. columns 1-3, become the new column 1, columns 4-6 becomes the new column 2, and so forth. So that my `100x300` matrix becomes a `100x100` matrix.

A matrix kinda like

```
A <- matrix(rexp(30000, rate=.1), ncol=300)
```

I tried something like this `rowMeans(A, 3)` unfortunately can not work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of averaging 9 columns into 3 columns

```
#DATA
set.seed(42)
m = matrix(rnorm(90), ncol = 9)

sapply(split(sequence(NCOL(m)), ceiling(sequence(NCOL(m))/3)), function(i) rowMeans(m[,i]))
#                1          2           3
# [1,]  0.78972984  0.3277913  0.03411781
# [2,] -0.01978707 -0.1466863  0.11765521
# [3,] -0.39921655  1.1229981  0.43126071
# [4,]  0.52291618 -0.2309106  0.10843898
# [5,]  0.72204682 -0.2578551 -0.82148326
# [6,]  0.03311892 -0.3358800  0.83184534
# [7,]  0.32333323 -0.3055211  0.29562900
# [8,] -1.50475918  0.2276755  0.43983899
# [9,]  0.01268471 -1.9462480  0.32276620
#[10,]  0.20580146  0.3255511  0.14762346
```